# When was it first mentioned that Colossus was made of osmium?

Tags: marvel, x-men, colossus

In many modern appearances, the [X-Man Colossus](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Piotr_Rasputin_(Earth-616)) is made of organic osmium, a particularly dense material. Of course, many of these "scientific" facts about superheroes were conceived long after the fact, like the Hulk's nanotube skin. Further, it's possible that the writers were originally going for a steel or iron look, to fit the Soviet theme (Stalin, meaning steel; the Iron Curtain; and other examples of steel being a Soviet motif).

In what issue was it first mentioned that Colossus was made of osmium? Was he ever described as being a different material?

Comment: I don't know that it's that cut and dried. The various wiki sites describe it as "organic steel" and note that it's "like osmium". I edited in one link. Can you provide others that state it is osmium?

Comment: There is no consistency about what Colossus's metallic form is made out of.  His official bio on Marvel.com, https://www.marvel.com/characters/colossus-piotr-rasputin says "steel," with no mention of osmium.  At various times, I know comics have indicated it was actual steel, "organic steel" (whatever that means), an organic steel-like material of unknown composition, osmium, osmium-doped steel (analogous to carbon steel), and probably other things.
An answerable question might be when some connection of Colossus's metal form to osmium was first introduced.